# Invalid syntax error in import tweepy

Tags: python

For the statement "import tweepy", I am getting the following syntax error:

```
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.2.0-py3.2.egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 149
  self._buffer = u""
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know why the interpreter is unable to understand this code.  This is probably due to mismatch of encoding between editor and interpreter. 
How do I overcome this? Currently using windows7, Python3.2, tweepy 3.2.0
command prompt sys.stdin.encoding says 'cp437'.

Comment: `u''` unicode literals aren't supported in Python 3.0-3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Tweepy is not compatible with Python 3.2. You'll need to upgrade to Python 3.3 or newer, or find a different Twitter library that supports Python 3.2.

From the [project page](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy):

> Python 2.6 and 2.7, 3.3 & 3.4 are supported.

Specifically, the error is caused by using `u'..'` string literals, which are only supported in 3.3 and up to help write *polyglot Python code*; code that works both on Python 2 and Python 3.